# Counting the lines in a file doesn't keep correct value once more code is added

Tags: arrays, c, file

I have a text file, containing 2 float numbers per line, and the file is 20 lines long.If i try to store the numbers in an array, and try to give the array a size by hand, it works. If i try to count the lines in the file, i get the correct answer : 20. But if i try to count the lines, then use the variable as size of the data array, the lines variable for some reason becomes a float = 200.

```
FILE *s;
s=fopen("short.txt", "r"); //file nev s!
int n=20;
char c;
int lines=0;
while(!feof(s))
{
    c=fgetc(s);
    if(c =='\n')
    {
        lines=lines+1;
    }

}

printf("%d", lines);

double data[n*2];

for(int i=0; i<n*2; i++)
{
   fscanf(s,"%lf",&data[i]);
}

fclose(s);
for(int i=0; i<n*2; i++)
{
    printf("%lf\n", data[i]);
}
```

Comment: Welcome! Please see [Why is `while ( !feof (file) )` always wrong?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feof-file-always-wrong) Next, look up the type that `fgetc()` returns, which isn't `char`.

Comment: Youv'e also reached the end of the file, so `fscanf()` won't read anything. Always check the return value (the number of items successfully read). Remember to `rewind(s);`

Comment: Please, show a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so we can test it, before giving you incorrect hints about how to solve your problem.